# Comparing values "in the different" in VBscripting Photoshop

Tags: vbscript, photoshop-script

In VB Script in Photoshop, is it possible to implement conditionals such as:

```
if A<>B Then
....code.... 
End if
```

I can compare equals, i.e. "if A=B etc etc", but I cannot find the syntax for comparing in the "different".

I have tried different combinations of syntax in line with what I know of coding (aka batting in the dark) to no avail.  BTW, this apparent limitation would not matter except that there is no GOTO avalibale here statements that I know of.
Regards,

Comment: Can you [edit] and add actual code you tried?

Comment: [Adobe Scripting](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html) can use VBScript, so the actual mechanism of [comparing values in VBScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/9hck4s70(v=vs.84)) will not change. In fact, Adode Script is completely irrelevant to the question. You just need to read the [VBScript documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/t0aew7h6(v=vs.84)).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it better to use NOT or <> when comparing values?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/369525)

Answer (score 0):

Of course that VBScript can use both equals and differents.
Example you showed is correct :

```
if (string<>"") then
   ...
end if
```

Can you show a sample of code you used ? Maybe the issue is somewhere else, like comparaison different kind of values (string vs number).